# how to create a csrf token in laravel 5.1 forms

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Token is important for security in Laravel. Can any one tell me how to use it in blades of Laravel 5.1

I used the following method:

```
<input type="hidden" value="csrf_token()" />
```

But i want it to be in the form :
Form::(some code)

Comment: use `{{ csrf_token() }}` or `{{ Form::token() }}`

Answer (score 0):

`{!! Form::token() !!}` will be helpful in Laravel 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5.1 haven't out of the box the Form component. You have to install from https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html